# Detecting if two images are similar

Tags: c#, java, c++, algorithm, image-processing

Could someone give me a push in the right direction, if I am willing to determine if
two images actually make a panorama together *(or are **panorama-like**, e.g contain "same" parts, which are obviously a bit transformed).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique you are after is known as "image stitching". There is a reasonable [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) on it. That gives a few hints about how the algorithm would work.

It's necessarily a tricky heuristic. You need to find groups of pixels that are similar (but obviously not identical). This could include parts that are rotated slightly, scaled slightly, or coloured slightly differently.

Comment: Nice, thank you. And do you have some thoughts for the case like if images don't satisfy these requirements fully - like I have 5 images, which "are near in panorama terms" (but not even close in pixel terms, simply **near**) and I have 3 images which aren't even from that panorama session - does some algorithm to distinguish them exist?

Comment: I assume any image stitching algorithm will take two images and find "similar" areas (where areas that have similar pixel areas that are differently rotated, scaled, or coloured would still count). If it can't find any similar areas it would reject the match. So hopefully it would be able to put the 5 images together and reject the other 3. Of course you can never say if it will work for sure, since it's a heuristic.

Answer (score 5):

There are several articles on stitching images together:

1. [Implementation of HDR panorama stitching algorithm](http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/hostings/cescg/CESCG-2006/papers/Szczecin-Ostiak-Piotr.pdf)
2. [Image Alignment and Stitching: A Tutorial](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70092)
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/automatic_panoramas.aspx

The last one is a good tutorial that uses the LGPL library [Accord.NET](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/).